# Doesn't "When asking" refer to "people"?

Tags: discussion, help-center, grammatical-correction

In the first sentence from https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example:

> When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem.

doesn't the "When asking a question" refer to "people" while it should be "you"? I'm not a native speaker, so I'm not sure, but it sounds wrong to me, like

> When people are asking a question, they will be better able to provide help if you provide...

See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214954/doesnt-when-asking-refer-to-people

Comment: No, the people are those *not* asking the question. The you is the asker.

Comment: Seems like a great question for [ell.se].

Comment: Actually [english.se] has a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148766/dangling-participles) about it, but I have to say, I like the answer here better.

Comment: @kabanus: So I created a duplicate: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214954/does-when-asking-refer-to-people-or-the-writer-in-this-context/214956#214956. :-)

Comment: There seem to a lot of people here willing to tell the asker here that he's straightforwardly wrong. That seems surprising given that *many* grammar guides would characterise the usage he's pointing to as an error of English and agree that his parsing of it is the only grammatically correct one. I can imagine lots of people - native and non-native speakers alike - being momentarily confused by that sentence. And it's easy to fix by chucking in a handful of extra words: *"When asking a question, bear in mind that people will be better able to provide help if ..."*

Comment: I find adding bears to an issue often produces more problems than it solves.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland Aaaah! A bear! There's a bear! It's ***in my mind***! Get it out! Help! Help!

Comment: @MarkAmery: The sentence (with the intended reading) is _not_ grammatically wrong. If anything, it is a _stylistic_ error, as it makes the sentence ambiguous in its interpretation, and burdens the reader with the task of disambiguation, which would in turn make it undesirable in good writing; but it is perfectly grammatical with both subject assignments for the participle.

Comment: I guess it could be rephrased to "When _you_ are asking a question, _other_ people will be better able to provide help if you ..." to be more explicit.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is known as a "dangling participle".  That is, the participle isn't modifying the subject of the sentence.  It is considered an error by many style guides. I found [this](https://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_30.htm) in a quick google search:

> In the sentence below, the modifying clause (Rushing to catch the bus) contains a participle (rushing). The participle is said to be dangling because the subject of the main clause (Bob's wallet) is not the thing modified by the initial modifying clause. It was not Bob's wallet that was rushing.
>
> > Rushing to catch the bus, Bob's wallet fell out of his pocket.

Of course, dangling participles occur all the time in normal English usage, so unconditionally considering them an error might be a bit strict.  I found [Steven Pinker on Why It’s Okay to Dangle Your Participle](https://www.thecut.com/2014/09/steven-pinker-dangling-your-participle-is-okay.html):

> **You’re not a fan of the “Gotcha gang,” as you call them — folks who take a narrow view of usage that often relies on questionable rules. You write, “In their zeal to purify usage and safeguard the language, they have made it difficult to think clearly about  felicity and expression and have muddied the task of explaining the art of writing.” Can you expand on that a little?**
>
> Absolutely. Many purists have remarkably little curiosity about the history of the language or the scholarly tradition of examining issues and usage. So a stickler insists that we never let a participle dangle, that you can’t say, “Turning the corner, a beautiful view awaited me,” for example. They never stopped to ask, “Where did that rule come from and what is its basis?” It was simply taught to them and so they reiterate it.
>
> But if you look either at the history of great writing and language as it’s been used by its exemplary stylists, you find that they use dangling modifiers all the time. And if you look at the grammar of English you find that there is no rule that prohibits a dangling modifier. If you look at the history of scholars who have examined the dangling modifier rule, you find that it was pretty much pulled out of thin air by one usage guide a century ago and copied into every one since, And you also find that lots of sentences read much better if you leave the modifier dangling.
>
> So all of these bodies of scholarship, of people who actually study language as it’s been used, language as its logic is dictated by its inherent grammar — that whole body of scholarship is simply not something that your typical stickler has ever looked up.
>
> **It sounds like the culprit here is outdated or useless rules.**
>
> Yes, combined with the psychology of hazing and initiation rites, namely, “I had to go through it and I’m none the worse — why should you have it any easier?”

Comment: Thanks! Could you repost your answer on https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214954/doesnt-when-asking-refer-to-people? I guess this question here is going to die soon. :-)

Comment: Done! https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/214956/97089

Comment: Seeing we are getting some lessons in English here. Should there be a "the" before catch in that first example?

Comment: @AndréKool Good catch! :) That "the" shouldn't be there.

Comment: You should post this on https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148766/dangling-participles as well. This is a great answer. I wish we could dup-close those questions to here.

Comment: @kabanus I found [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/381464/351917) which I think makes the point as well as I ever could. I edited the answer to improve the formatting; my edit is in the review queue.

Comment: a dangling participle !? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4vf8N6GpdM

Answer (score 7):

Nope.

The *When asking* part refers to the actor, which is you, in this case.

*When <verb>, then <advice>* is a common sentence construction to give advice in general to anyone doing *<verb>*, and properly refers to the actor.

<sub>substantially edited because I first misunderstood the question</sub>

Comment: I'm either misunderstanding the question or misunderstanding your answer, but I would say the *"When asking a question"* *does* refer to you, rather than people, as in: *"When* ***you're*** *asking a question, people will be better able to provide help..."*

Comment: Ah, I might've misunderstood this question. The _Nope_ part is still true, though, the rest no longer applies if your explanation of the question is correct

Comment: I parse it as "When people are asking a question, they will be better able to provide help if you provide..."

Comment: That's not correct. If you want a deeper discussion on the English involved here, I suggest going to [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (I'm not that good at explaining), but I believe this sentence construction is quite unambiguous, _When asking a question_ refers to the actor, so only the person asking the question, while _people_ refers to all people.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214954/doesnt-when-asking-refer-to-people

Comment: Shall I close or delete the question here?